# How can I check for java security compatibility on certain sites before I update

Tags: java, updates

I have rolled out java 8 version 131, and am getting errors on certain websites. Is there a way to test these patches before I roll out the updates, and check for compatibility on certain websites?

Comment: Please provide the context/background, where you're using Java.

Comment: And what errors on what sites.

Comment: Compatibility on certain websites? What should be compatible with what?

Comment: I am using java version 8 update 131 in my group policy. My staff are encountering security errors on certain websites. I would like to check the sites that we use often are compatible with upcoming java updates before I update.. Is this possible?

Comment: Also I might add these are automotive sites, some slightly dated, and we are using IE. I'm more or less looking for some kind of compatibility check tool.. is there is such a thing.